# Group Dictionary by Key

Tags: c#

```
var invalidPageNumberAndSize = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"0","0"},
    {"0", ""},
    {"", "0"},
    {"abc", ""},
    {"", "abc"},
    {"abc", "abc"},
};
```

this will error if I try to loopit because I have 2 of the same key for each of these (I have 2 "0", and so on) so it'll throw a dup key error in my loop.

How can I make this work?

Comment: A `dictionary` is used if you want to have unique keys. You will need to look into a different method to hold your data.

Comment: I can do grouping can't i to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe you can use a List<Tuple<string,string>>

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a dictionary if you need to have multiple, duplicate keys.

One option is that you can have a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` or similar (where each key can have multiple values.  This is a bit more work to populate, but supports this type of scenario.  Another option would be to use a [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460184(v=vs.100).aspx).

That being said, given your variable names, I'd rethink what you're trying to do.  Storing a "size" and a "page number" as strings seems inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Lookup.  It's going to act kind of like the dictionary but it's immutable and will group the data.  You would use Contains instead of contains key and you don't get the nice initializer syntax.

```
var invalidPageNumberAndSizeData = new[] {
        new { key = "0", value = "0"},
        new { key = "0",  value = ""},
        new { key = "",  value = "0"},
        new { key = "abc",  value = ""},
        new { key = "",  value = "abc"},
        new { key = "abc",  value = "abc"}
    };


var invalidPageNumberAndSize = invalidPageNumberAndSizeData.ToLookup(c => c.key, c => c.value);
var isAbc = invalidPageNumberAndSize.Contains("abc");
var abcData = invalidPageNumberAndSize["abc"];
```

Comment: @CoffeeAddict I see you removed your question about the lookup.  If you see the invalidatPAgeNumberAndSizeData is an array of anonymous types and not a dictionary.